# How to generate sublists with elements within each line of a text file

Tags: python, arrays

How to generate `sublists` with elements within each line of a text file?

**SCRIPT**

```
 lines = tuple (open ('result.log', 'r'))
```

**result.log**

```
 ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', None)
 ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', None)
```

**GENERATE OUTPUT**

```
 ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', None]
 ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', None]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
 [['value1'], ['value2'], ['value3'], None]
 [['value1'], ['value2'], ['value3'], None]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```
lines = tuple ({'value1', 'value2', 'value3', None})
[[l] if l else l for l in lines]
```

Output:

```
[None, ['value2'], ['value1'], ['value3']]
```